# Restore multiple database files into multiple directories getting error on script

Tags: sql-server

I am running a script that is getting an error. When I comment out a section of the script, it says its successful - but nothing was actually done. The script is a restore script of multiple databases in multiple directories. The script is supposed to restore those databases back into a directory with the same name as the database. I will attach the script here:

```
   use [master]
GO

set nocount on

declare @curdir nvarchar(400)
declare @line varchar(400)
declare @command varchar(400)
declare @counter bigint
Declare @Database_name varchar(400)
Declare @directory varchar(400)
Declare @filename_name varchar(400)
declare @is_final_restore varchar(1)

set @is_final_restore = 'N'

If (select count (*) from sys.objects where name='Output') <> 0 DROP TABLE output  
If (select count (*) from tempdb.sys.objects where name like '%#Tempoutput%') <> 0 DROP TABLE #Tempoutput   
If (select count (*) from tempdb.sys.objects where name like '%#dirs%') <> 0 DROP TABLE #dirs   

create table #dirs (DIRID bigint identity(1,1), directory varchar(400))
  Set @command = 'dir "E:\MVE_Backups\Full" /S/B/A:A'
 insert into #dirs exec xp_cmdshell @command
  set @counter = (select count(*) from #dirs)
create table #tempoutput (line varchar(400))

create table output (Path_name varchar(400),Directory varchar(400),Files varchar(400),Database_name varchar(400), FileSize varchar(400))
    While @Counter <> 0
      Begin
        Declare @filesize bigint
        set @curdir = (select directory from #dirs where DIRID = @counter)
        set @command = 'dir "' + @curdir +'"'
        insert into #tempoutput
        exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @command
           select @line = ltrim(replace(substring(line, charindex(')', line)+1,len(line)), ',', ''))
           from #tempoutput where line like '%File(s)%bytes'
           Set @filesize  = Replace(@line, ' bytes', '')
           Set @filename_name = reverse(left(reverse(@curdir), charindex('\', reverse(@curdir)) -1))
           Set @directory  = reverse(Right(reverse(@curdir), len(@curdir)-charindex('\', reverse(@curdir))))
           Set @Database_name = reverse(left(reverse(@directory), charindex('\', reverse(@directory)) -1))
        Insert into output (Path_name,Directory, Files,Database_name, Filesize) values (@curdir,@directory,@filename_name,@Database_name, @filesize)
        Set @counter = @counter -1
       End
  Delete from output where Path_name is null

DECLARE @fname VARCHAR(200) 
DECLARE @dirfile VARCHAR(300) 
DECLARE @LogicalName NVARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @PhysicalName NVARCHAR(260) 
DECLARE @type CHAR(1) 
DECLARE @DbName sysname 
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000) 

  --- Create Temp tables for Restoring


CREATE TABLE #bdev( 
 BackupName NVARCHAR(128) 
,BackupDescription NVARCHAR(255) 
,BackupType smallint 
,ExpirationDate datetime 
,Compressed tinyint 
,Position smallint 
,DeviceType tinyint 
,UserName NVARCHAR(128) 
,ServerName NVARCHAR(128) 
,DatabaseName NVARCHAR(128) 
,DatabaseVersion INT 
,DatabaseCreationDate datetime 
,BackupSize numeric(20,0) 
,FirstLSN numeric(25,0) 
,LastLSN numeric(25,0) 
,CheckpointLSN numeric(25,0) 
,DatabaseBackupLSN numeric(25,0) 
,BackupStartDate datetime 
,BackupFinishDate datetime 
,SortOrder smallint 
,CodePage smallint 
,UnicodeLocaleId INT 
,UnicodeComparisonStyle INT 
,CompatibilityLevel tinyint 
,SoftwareVendorId INT 
,SoftwareVersionMajor INT 
,SoftwareVersionMinor INT 
,SoftwareVersionBuild INT 
,MachineName NVARCHAR(128) 
,Flags INT 
,BindingID uniqueidentifier 
,RecoveryForkID uniqueidentifier 
,Collation NVARCHAR(128) 
,FamilyGUID uniqueidentifier 
,HasBulkLoggedData INT 
,IsSnapshot INT 
,IsReadOnly INT 
,IsSingleUser INT 
,HasBackupChecksums INT 
,IsDamaged INT 
,BegibsLogChain INT 
,HasIncompleteMetaData INT 
,IsForceOffline INT 
,IsCopyOnly INT 
,FirstRecoveryForkID uniqueidentifier 
,ForkPointLSN numeric(25,0) 
,RecoveryModel NVARCHAR(128) 
,DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0) 
,DifferentialBaseGUID uniqueidentifier 
,BackupTypeDescription NVARCHAR(128) 
,BackupSetGUID uniqueidentifier 
,CompressedBackupSize bigint
) 

--Table to hold result from RESTORE FILELISTONLY. Need to generate the MOVE options to the RESTORE command 
CREATE TABLE #dbfiles( 
 LogicalName NVARCHAR(128) 
,PhysicalName NVARCHAR(260) 
,Type CHAR(1) 
,FileGroupName NVARCHAR(128) 
,Size numeric(20,0) 
,MaxSize numeric(20,0) 
,FileId INT 
,CreateLSN numeric(25,0) 
,DropLSN numeric(25,0) 
,UniqueId uniqueidentifier 
,ReadOnlyLSN numeric(25,0) 
,ReadWriteLSN numeric(25,0) 
,BackupSizeInBytes BIGINT 
,SourceBlockSize INT 
,FilegroupId INT 
,LogGroupGUID uniqueidentifier 
,DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25) 
,DifferentialBaseGUID uniqueidentifier 
,IsReadOnly INT 
,IsPresent INT 
,TDEThumbPrint uniqueidentifier 
) 

DECLARE dbfiles CURSOR FOR 
SELECT LogicalName, PhysicalName, Type FROM #dbfiles 

declare backup_cur cursor for
    select Path_name, Database_name from output 
open backup_cur

fetch next from backup_cur into @filename_name, @database_name

--Loop through each script.
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    if @is_final_restore = 'Y'
    BEGIN
        set @dirfile = @filename_name

        set @Database_name = @Database_name + '_temp'

        print 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + @database_name + '] FROM  DISK = N''' + @dirfile + ''' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD'
        print 'GO'
        print 'USE [' + @database_name + ']'
        print 'GO'
        print 'sp_changedbowner ''' + @database_name + '_user'''
        print 'GO'
        print 'USE [master]'
        print 'GO'
        print 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @database_name + '] SET TRUSTWORTHY on'
        print 'GO'
        print 'GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO [' + @database_name + '_user]'
        print 'GO'
        print 'sp_configure ''clr enabled'', 1'
        print 'GO'
        print 'reconfigure'
        print 'GO'
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN

        --PRINT ('Now Restoring Database '+ @database_name+' in Non-Recovery Mode. From File :'+@filename_name  )
        set @dirfile = @filename_name
        --Get database name from RESTORE HEADERONLY, assumes there's only one backup on each backup file. 
        TRUNCATE TABLE #bdev 
        INSERT #bdev 
        EXEC('RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = ''' + @dirfile + '''') 
        SET @DbName = (SELECT DatabaseName FROM #bdev) 

        --Construct the beginning for the RESTORE DATABASE command 
        SET @sql = 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + @DbName + '] FROM DISK = ''' + @dirfile + ''' WITH NORECOVERY, MOVE ' 

        --Get information about database files from backup device into temp table 
        TRUNCATE TABLE #dbfiles 
        INSERT #dbfiles 
        EXEC('RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ''' + @dirfile + '''') 

        OPEN dbfiles 
        FETCH NEXT FROM dbfiles INTO @LogicalName, @PhysicalName, @type 
        --For each database file that the database uses 
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN 
        IF @type = 'D' 
        SET @sql = @sql + '''' + @LogicalName + ''' TO ''' + 'F:\Database_Files\'+@database_name+'\' + @LogicalName  + '.mdf'', MOVE ' 
        ELSE IF @type = 'L' 
        SET @sql = @sql + '''' + @LogicalName + ''' TO ''' + 'F:\Database_Files\'+@database_name+'\' + @LogicalName + '.ldf''' 
        FETCH NEXT FROM dbfiles INTO @LogicalName, @PhysicalName, @type 
        END 
        PRINT ('EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'''+'F:\Database_Files\'+@database_name+'''')
        PRINT ('GO')
        PRINT @SQL
        PRINT ('GO')
        close dbfiles
    END
fetch next from backup_cur into @filename_name, @database_name  
END

close backup_cur
deallocate backup_cur
DEALLOCATE dbfiles 

drop table output;

drop table #bdev
drop table #dbfiles
```

The error when I run this is:

Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.

The code I comment out is this:

```
BEGIN
    set @dirfile = @filename_name

    set @Database_name = @Database_name + '_temp'

    print 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + @database_name + '] FROM  DISK = N''' + @dirfile + ''' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD'
    print 'GO'
    print 'USE [' + @database_name + ']'
    print 'GO'
    print 'sp_changedbowner ''' + @database_name + '_user'''
    print 'GO'
    print 'USE [master]'
    print 'GO'
    print 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @database_name + '] SET TRUSTWORTHY on'
    print 'GO'
    print 'GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO [' + @database_name + '_user]'
    print 'GO'
    print 'sp_configure ''clr enabled'', 1'
    print 'GO'
    print 'reconfigure'
    print 'GO'
END

ELSE
```

Comment: The error message seems quite clear. What version of SQL Server is it? As I noted in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413326/how-to-insert-into-a-temp-table-the-info-given-by-restore-filelistonly-headero), I found that the result set from `RESTORE HEADERONLY` didn't match the documentation, but of course it's simple to fix that yourself by modifying the table structure. Have you verified that your `#bdev` table structure does indeed match the output from `RESTORE HEADERONLY` exactly? And you didn't say *which* piece of code you comment out to run it.

Comment: I added the code... I am moving from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2012 both enterprise editions. The table structures are the same, Im just moving one database backup to a new server. I can do this easily one by one, but with this script, it fails. I have over 100 to do, so I wanted to make it a little more automated than doing it one by one...

Comment: Also, if I try to create the tables individually, they work just fine on both servers.

Comment: Now getting this error:
Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are restoring the backups on a SQL Serve 2012 server. As the documentation [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536.aspx), the result set from `RESTORE HEADERONLY` has an extra column called `containment` that was not in SQL 2008, but your `#bdev` table has no `containment` column. If you add it, then the `RESTORE HEADERONLY` results will match the table structure.

Personally, I would use an external script to do this instead of TSQL. It's just easier to work with files using an external script, and all the dynamic SQL is difficult to read and troubleshoot. Using [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) from PowerShell is one option, or just use your preferred scripting language to execute TSQL.

Comment: I understand - some find it easier to use certain methods, for me personally, I find it easier to write in TSQL - I found the documentation and hadn't seen your comment. After I submitted my answer, the page refreshed and your answer showed up! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was... going from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2012, there was additional column that was missing when creating #bdev.

I resolved the issue by checking the table structure of both SQL servers and determined that in SQL 2012, they added a new column which was not in my script... when adding this column, the script worked fine!